# WebDrive Proxi and mi profile same time

Tags: python, webdriver, proxies

I have this problem and need to solve it, I use webdrive.chrome and if I connect

```
##chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Beast\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
##chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=HENG_KH-001")
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(hostname + ":" + port))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
##extension='extension_4_18_1_0.crx'
##chrome_options.add_extension(extension)
```

so I'm connected to the proxy, but if I turn on the profile, what is the creation of the profile, but the proxy is ignored? Can anyone think of a way to solve this?

I expect that the profile will connect via proxy, the proxy will be turned on there

however, if they uncomment the profile, a new profile will be connected to the proxy / if not, my IP address will be connected with the profile